# PHP (Joomla 2.5) execution not returning to Apache?

Tags: php, performance, apache, joomla, amazon-web-services

I have a Joomla (2.5) site that sporadically hangs in its response.  PHP seems to do its thing in a reasonable amount of time, but the response hits apache's time limit.

**New Relic Stack Trace:**
[image: New Relic Trace]

I've never seen this before, but I've also never developed Joomla sites before.  Is this common to Joomla?  How would you go about debugging this?

**Additional details:**

- I don't see any relevant error log records
- Extra-large EC2 instance, RDS database, Ubuntu 12.10
- Apache2, PHP 5.3 installed from `apt-get`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been running a joomla site on aws for half year now having similar issues and it seems to be related to amazon somehow. Sometimes it opens too many mysql connections resulting in these hangs in ec2-rds layer

After lots of investigations we've resolved this by adding additional instance working as a failover machine. Concluding, this is definitely not joomla issue, either you have same issue we have or your apache php-handler is misconfigured.

Enable CloudWatch for your ec2 and RDS instances and watch for number of connections to the database when the site seems frozen. If you see a spike you have the same issue

Comment: Btw. Aws logs are useless, these from EC2 as well as these from RDS